# Can Dynamic and Constantly changing image URL work with Next/image

Tags: reactjs, next.js, nextjs-image

**Can Next/Image use empty string variables for the src that'd get set later via an API?**

I have an image url that I'd retrieve from an API. so the image src gets set after runtime. By default it's an empty string `''` and then using SWR later it gets set to the full image url, eg `https://i.imgur.com/Thgw1b.png`

However, I get a build time error, `` Error: Image is missing required "src" property. Make sure you pass "src" in props to the `next/image` component. Received: {} `` despite having src already set. The same error occurs if `src=''` as well.

```
const myComponent = ({imageURL = ''}) => {
  // imageURL starts off as '', then the parent updates that value to a proper image url when the API returns a url value. 

  return (
    <>
      // TODO: Fix build time error saying no src is set, despite being set to '' initially
      <Image src={imageURL} alt='Dynamic Image' layout='responsive'/>
    </>
  );
}
```

Can Next/Image src images be set fully dynamically? Where it starts as an empty string then the src url gets populated later?

I've seen some answers suggesting **useServerSide Props**, but that won't work in my use case as the image url API gives a different image url every X hours (Hence using SWR). So just loading in once doesn't work.

**Note that using `<img>` tags works perfectly.** Initially there's no image, then after the image url gets set to the variable, the img tag loads the image in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try rendering the `Image` conditionally like so :

```
return (
    <>
      {imageUrl &&
        <Image src={imageURL} alt='Dynamic Image' layout='responsive'/>
      }
    </>
)
```

Comment: Well, that was a minor oversight